# Lean: how to use the refine_struct tactic for commutative ring structures?

Tags: lean, lean-mathlib

Suppose I want to make `bool` (i.e. the type `{ff,tt}` of boolean values) into a commutative ring.  The following works:

```
instance : comm_ring bool := {
  zero := ff,
  add := bxor,
  neg := id,
  one := tt,
  mul := band,
  zero_add      := by { repeat { rintro ⟨_⟩ };  refl },
  add_zero      := by { repeat { rintro ⟨_⟩ };  refl },
  one_mul       := by { repeat { rintro ⟨_⟩ };  refl },
  mul_one       := by { repeat { rintro ⟨_⟩ };  refl },
  add_left_neg  := by { repeat { rintro ⟨_⟩ };  refl },
  add_comm      := by { repeat { rintro ⟨_⟩ };  refl },
  mul_comm      := by { repeat { rintro ⟨_⟩ };  refl },
  add_assoc     := by { repeat { rintro ⟨_⟩ };  refl },
  mul_assoc     := by { repeat { rintro ⟨_⟩ };  refl },
  left_distrib  := by { repeat { rintro ⟨_⟩ };  refl },
  right_distrib := by { repeat { rintro ⟨_⟩ };  refl }
}
```

In other words, I define zero=false, addition=xor and so on.  Then I have to check a bunch of identities, each of which is quantified over one, two or three variables of type `bool`.  I introduce as many variables as necessary, split cases according to whether each variable is true or false, and then just apply the definitions to check that the axiom holds in each case.

The [refine_struct](https://leanprover-community.github.io/mathlib_docs/tactics.html#refine_struct) tactic is supposed to tidy up this sort of thing.  My expectation was that this would work:

```
instance : comm_ring bool := begin
 refine_struct { zero := ff, add := bxor, neg := id, one := tt, mul := band };
 repeat { rintro ⟨_⟩ };
 refl
end
```

Here the `refine_struct` tactic is supposed to create 11 goals, one for each of the axioms `zero_add`,...,`right_distrib`.  This is followed by the tactics `repeat { rintro ⟨_⟩ }` and `refl`.  The three tactics are separated by semicolons so each tactic is applied to all goals generated by the previous tactic.  I had code similar to this which worked correctly in November 2021. However, this approach now fails.

If we replace the semicolon after `refine_struct {...}` by a comma and place the cursor there, we see the list of goals created by `refine_struct`.  Firstly, the documentation for `refine_struct` says that these goals should be tagged with the names of the corresponding fields (i.e. `zero_add`, `mul_assoc` and so on), but I do not see any tags (in VS Code); am I misunderstanding something here?  Secondly, there are actually 23 goals rather than 11, some of which are goals to supply extra structures rather than verify axioms.  By comparison with mathlib's [ring structure on the reals](https://github.com/leanprover-community/mathlib/blob/master/src/data/real/basic.lean#L65), I gather that we need to supply the subtraction map `bool → bool → bool`, scalar multiplication maps `ℕ → bool → bool` and `ℤ → bool → bool` and the power map `ℕ → bool → bool`, and then verify that these satisfy certain axioms.  However, in my first approach all this is done silently and automatically.  Is there a way to make `refine_struct` work as it did before?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What changed since November 2021​​​ is that `comm_ring` got several new data members in order to resolve various diamond issues. `refine_struct` does not supply these members, and although you can supply the default value it requires you to stage the definition, not going straight to `comm_ring` but building up from at least a few of the ancestor classes first.

It's not super satisfactory, but this works:

```
import tactic

instance : comm_ring bool := begin
  letI : has_zero bool := ⟨ff⟩,
  letI : has_one bool := ⟨tt⟩,
  letI : has_add bool := ⟨bxor⟩,
  letI : has_mul bool := ⟨band⟩,
  letI : has_neg bool := ⟨id⟩,
  refine_struct { zero := ff, add := (+), neg := id, one := tt, mul := (*),
    sub := (+), nsmul := nsmul_rec, npow := npow_rec, zsmul := zsmul_rec };
  repeat { rintro ⟨_⟩ };
  refl
end
```